# Using paste with Parentheses in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, paste, parentheses

I'm having problems when using `paste` with parentheses inside Makefile.

The instruction  I'm trying to run is:

```
paste -d " " <(cat file1) <(cat file2 | grep "pattern")
```

If I run it from the console it works correctly, however when putting it inside a Makefile the parenthesis causes a syntax error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Basically what I need is to paste the contents of two (or more) files but filtering some of them with grep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to tell make what shell you want to use. The default one (`/bin/sh`) does not support the process substitution syntax. Put

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

somewhere at the top of the Makefile.